# You do not have correct permissions to add apps to this app service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-plans

I want to add three `wordpress`-based web apps to my currently existing Azure Service Plan. I have a Premium plan (`P1V2`), whose location is marked as `East US 2`, and has the appropriate Resource groups created.

However, when it prompts me to select a Subscription for my app and I do, I get this error:

> You do not have correct permissions to add apps to this app service plan

Which appears directly next to the default App Service Plan associated with it.

I have global administrator access on my account, so permissions should not be a problem,but I'm still getting this error. How can I fix it?

See screenshot of error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have global administrator access on my account, so permissions should not be a problem,but I'm still getting this error. How can I fix it?

The global administrator is a role in Azure AD, not represents you have the direct permissions in the subscription.

Please follow the steps below:

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory`-> `Properties` in the portal, make sure the setting as below is `Yes`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the subscription which you want to do the operations -> `Access control (IAM)`, add your account as an `Owner`, then the error will be fixed.

[image]